# The same compilation works from command line but not from Xcode IDE

Tags: xcode, build, fortran, ide, intel

I am trying to build a Fortran project in the Xcode IDE using Intel compilers. If I start the build phase I get an error as seen in the image (strangely I don't get the lines where the error is, I only get `Command /usr/local/bin/ifort-19.0.3.199 failed with exit code 2`).

[image]

However if I run the exact same command in the terminal I get a proper compilation.

```
[ED]$ cd ED2
[ED2]$ /usr/local/bin/ifort-19.0.3.199 -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.14 -g -O0 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -mno-omit-leaf-frame-pointer -assume nobuffered_io -mkl=parallel -I/Users/manfredo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ED2-bzpotpyhearnjhdlpmzxdtkugvki/Build/Products/Debug/include -I/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2019.3.199/mac/mkl/include -I/usr/local/hdf-1-10.5/include -I/Users/manfredo/Documents/Eclipse_workspace/ED2/ED/src/include -assume cc-omp -reentrancy threaded -nopad_source -altparam -nod-lines -qopenmp -novms -nof77rtl -nointconstant -assume nobscc -warn nostderrors -warn nodeclarations -warn nounused -warn noignore-loc -warn notruncated-source -warn noalignments -warn nouncalled -warn usage -warn nointerfaces -warn noshape -init=nosnan -init=nozero -align nosequence -assume nodummy_aliases -assume protect-constants -assume nobyterecl -fno-zero-initialized-in-bss -fp-model no-except -nofltconsistency -no-fp-port -no-ftz -nofpconstant -assume nominus0 -no-complex-limited-range -assume nounderscore -nogen-interfaces -module /Users/manfredo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ED2-bzpotpyhearnjhdlpmzxdtkugvki/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ED2.build/Debug -notraceback -check nobounds -check nooutput-conversion -check noformat -check noarg-temp-created -check nopointers -check nouninit -check nostack -check noshape -c /Users/manfredo/Documents/Eclipse_workspace/ED2/ED/src/memory/ed_max_dims.F90 -o /Users/manfredo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ED2-bzpotpyhearnjhdlpmzxdtkugvki/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ED2.build/Debug/ED2.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ed_max_dims.o
[ED2]$
```

Furthermore this problem seems to happen at random. Here this is the very first file that is compiled. Other times the build proceeds for a few files and then throws this error. In every case if I past the Xcode compilation command in the command line I get a clean compilation.

Comment: If you re-run the same build, it sometimes fails at a different point?  That sounds like your hardware is failing.  Check your CPU fan / temperature, and run a memtest of some sort and/or a Prime95 stress test.

Comment: No I guess it's something different, probably due to the very limited support for fortran in Xcode. But going with order, why a command in Xcode would fail when the same command in the terminal works?

Comment: That makes no sense unless the current directory is different, or environment vars are different, or if your GUI isn't accurately reporting what it ran.  Maybe use `strace` or `truss` or whatever OS X has to trace system calls made by Xcode to see exactly how it invokes `ifort` with an `execve` system call.